# How to remove outlier values while reading a file

Tags: r

I have a large number of files, each in tab-delimited format. I need to apply some modeling (glm/gbm etc) on each of these files. They are obtained from hospital data where in exceptional cases entries may not be the proper format. For example, when entering `glucose` level for a patient, the data entry operator may enter `N` or `A` by mistake instead of actual number.

While reading these files in loop, I am encountering problem as such columns (glucose) are treated as factor while it should be a numeric. It is painful to investigate each file and and look for error. I am reading the files in the following way but it is certainly not a good approach.

```
read.table(fn, header = TRUE,  sep= "\t" , na.strings = c('',  'NEG', 'TR', 'NA', '<NA>', "Done", "D", "A"))
```

Is there any other function through which I can assume those values/outliers to be `na`?

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect which elements are not number (for the glucose case):

```
data = read.csv(file, as.is = TRUE, sep = '\t') # dont convert string to factor
glucose = data$glucose

sapply(glucose, function(x)!is.na(as.numeric(x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Then you can work with these indexes (interpolate or remove).

To loop the files:

```
files = list.files(path, '*.csv')
for (file in files)
{
  data = read.csv(file, sep = '\t', as.is = TRUE)
  gluc = data$glucose
  idxs = sapply(gluc, function(x)!is.na(as.numeric(x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  # interpolate or remove here
}
```

Comment: thanks. I need to do it for all files. `glucose` was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `colClasses` argument to `read.table` and friends to specify which columns should be numeric, then R does not need to try and guess.  If a column is designated to be numeric then any entries that are not numbers will be converted to `NA` automatically.